# UWP INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, inotifydataerrorinfo

Do controls on the UWP platform automatically support the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface through binding?

On Silverlight and WPF, if we implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface, most controls will automatically glow red and display an error message when the field is in error. This is great functionality as it means that you can place errors at the model level instead of at the control level.

Is this supported in UWP? Are there any samples anywhere?

*Edit: It seems as though the answer to this question might be that controls in UWP don't handle INotifyDataErrorInfo at all. So, the question now is, if the functionality is not being used, does the Microsoft team plan to implement the functionality in future? Is there an announcement from Microsoft anywhere on this?*

Comment: Have you actually looked on the internet first?

Comment: This is what I Googled: 'uwp INotifyDataErrorInfo example'. It had some leads that went nowhere, with no examples.

Answer (score 2):

Not supported today. Here is a related UserVoice [link](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/13052589-uwp-input-validation) for you to comment and vote:

Comment: Voted. Although, this item doesn't specifically talk about INotifyDataErrorInfo. Will leave this thread open for a while to see if anyone has any more info.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in this channel9 video: https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2018/BRK3502?term=lob%20uwp&lang-en=true

There will be System.ComponententModel.INotifyDataErrorInfo to re-use existing .NET code, and also Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyDataErrorInfo to make the functionality also available to C++ developers.

In the future controls will support these interfaces.

Comment: How long in the future?  This stuff is taking forever.  I think line-of-business programmers should be rightly nervous about building UWP xaml apps since Microsoft doesn't seem to prioritize these types of basic requirements.  Another example is the UWP datagrid in the community technical preview which was finally released - taking about five years longer than anyone would have expected.